# RPi 3 B with Raspbian, LibreELEC and RetroPie?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, retropie

Can anyone tell me how to install Raspbian, RetroPie and LibreELEC on the same SDcard.
I just bought a **Raspberry Pi 3 Model B**. I downloaded NOOBS and could only see, even with wired connection to the internet:

- Raspbian
- LibreELEC
- OSMC
- Windows 10 IoT Core

So, I've now installed **Raspbian** and **LibreELEC**. I would like to install **RetroPie** and use a USBstick to the games. I've tried to install it from the terminal, but without success. I can not put RetroPie img onto the SDcard, where the other two OS’ are?

Can you tell me what and how I do, I'm new in this world.

Thanks guys

Comment: I think you can use BerryBoot.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy step-by-step to apply a NOOBS based image of RetroPie on your device, neither there exists an image provided by the RetroPie team using the NOOBS format. You will have to basically download the RetroPie img, write it to another device(could be a spare sdcard or usb stick), and then follow the steps that are at the External Resources section of this answer.

**External Resources:**

- [Convert RetroPie SD Card Image to NOOBS Image](https://github.com/retropie/retropie-setup/wiki/convert-retropie-sd-card-image-to-noobs-image)